# Sphinx sort mode not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, centos, sphinx

I am using the following code:

```
include('sphinxapi.php');
$search = "John"
$s = new SphinxClient;
$s->SetServer("localhost", 9312);
$s->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, 'name ASC');
$nameindex = $s->Query("$search");
echo $nameindex['total_found'];
```

This returns a blank page however without the SetSortMode it works fine and returns the number of results. No matter what I set the SetSortMode to it does not work. **Any ideas as to why this would be?**

I am indexing one column called **name**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sort by (normal) fields in Sphinx, only attributes, or fields marked with the sql_field_string setting (which creates an attribute of the same name). So you'll need to either add an attribute with the same column, or use sql_field_string - they're equivalent.

Also: I've removed the thinking-sphinx tag - you're not using Ruby, and thus not the Thinking Sphinx library.